# Command line spellchecker for Finnish

Tags: windows, command-line, spell-checker

Would you know where I could get a command line spellchecker (Windows binary if possible) that I can use in noninteractive mode for Finnish (in order to filter a list of strings that can be words or nonwords)?

I heard that Hunspell was inappropriate for Finnish.
I tried Aspell but I am not satisfied with the result ("tainnuttaa" is considered as a mispelled word for instance).

Comment: Sounds like the main issue is finding a good Aspell dictionary for Finnish: you might want to ask for one on the opendata SE.

Answer (score 1):

A five step process:

1. Install [Python](http://www.python.org) for [windows](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.8/).
2. Install [pyEnchant](http://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/) from [here](http://pypi.python.org/packages/any/p/pyenchant/pyenchant-1.6.6.win32.exe) or with `pip install pyenchant`.
3. Add the dictionary from [here](http://archive.services.openoffice.org/pub/mirror/OpenOffice.org/contrib/dictionaries/) per [these instructions](http://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/tutorial.html#adding-language-dictionaries).
4. Make sure that you have both python and its scripts directory on your path, if you used the default installation, these will be C:\python and C:\python\scripts on windows.
5. Write a simple script to process words you type, words from the command line or the words in a file the [tutorials](http://pythonhosted.org/pyenchant/tutorial.html) should give you a very good starting point. e.g.:

   ```
   import sys
   import enchant

   d = enchant.Dict("fi_FI")

   if len(sys.argv) < 2:
       print "To use this script supply the words to check on the command line"
   for word in sys.argv[1:]:
       print word, d.check(word)
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear answer!
Unfortunately I did all the above steps and Python returns the following code after "import enchant":`  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\enchant\__init__.py", line 92, in <module>

    from enchant import _enchant as _e
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\enchant\_enchant.py", line 102, in <module
>
    raise WinError()
WindowsError: [Error 193] <no description>`

Comment: I solved the problem with Enchant. It was not working with Python 64bits. Unfortunately enchant cannot find the finnish dictionary. I looked in the fi_FI.zip archive and observed that the files were empty. I'm trying with this [one](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/myspell-fi).

Comment: You need the windows build of libvokko from here: http://www.puimula.org/htp/testing/voikko-sdk/win-crossbuild/ for the backend.

Answer (score 1):

**Tmispell**  is  an  **ispell**  wrapper  which  uses ***Voikko spell-checking*** system to do the actual spell-checking for **Finnish** language.
 Tmispell is a transparent wrapper for Ispell, other programs that would normally  use  Ispell  will  automatically  use Tmispell (and therefore Voikko) without any changes needed.

For more information visit this link: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/tmispell.1.html

I hope your problem will resolve out.